# How to use a 2d array in other function?? don't know how to make it work

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, pass-by-reference

me and my friend are trying to pass a user-defined array to a function and do a "2d array" sort mechanism on that array which is defined outside the function.

we found a function online that sorts a predefined array within itself and tried to use that function.

our problem consist in trying to use the user-defined array in the function.

please check the code below (please note that we don't know how to use structs)

The question is: how do we use our orderListArray[][] in the sort array function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// define for sort array function later on
#define ARRAYSIZE(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*(array)))

// function prototype
int sortArray();
int printOrderlist();


// data variables to be used throughout the code.
int itemNumber;
int itemAmount;
int maxItem = 0;
int lineCount = 0;
int priceToPrint = 0;
float totalPrice = 0;

// array we wish to implement into "sortArray" function
int orderListArray[][2];



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int orderList()
{ // begin orderList

// makes sure user enters a maximum of 5 orders
int k = 0; // first place in array
int g = 0; // second place in array

do
{ // begin do1
    printf("%d %d\n", k,g);
    // asks for item number
    puts("Enter item number (1-100):");
    scanf("%d", &itemNumber);
    // add scan to first spot (k) which is 0,0 (row 0, spot 0)
    orderListArray[k][g] = itemNumber;
    // add g++ to go to 0,1 ( row 0, spot 1)
    g++; 
    // asks for amount
    printf("%d %d\n", k, g);
    printf("You can order %d more items\n", 5-itemAmount);
    printf("Enter amount:\n");
    scanf("%d", &itemAmount);
    maxItem = maxItem + itemAmount;
    // add itemAmount to g which is 0,1 
    orderListArray[k][g] = itemAmount;
    k++; // go to row 1 instead of row 0
    g--; // go back to spot 0 in row.
    // lineCount is used when we print rows of array since that is not predefined
    lineCount++;
} // end do1
// runs as long as the total amount of items inputed matches.
while (maxItem <= 4);

return 0;
} // end orderList

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////


int main(void)
{
orderList();

sortArray();

return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////

// is used in sortArray() to sort 2d array.
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
int x1 = *(const int*)a;
int x2 = *(const int*)b;
if (x1 > x2) return  1;
if (x1 < x2) return -1;
// x1 and x2 are equal; compare y's
int y1 = *(((const int*)a)+1);
int y2 = *(((const int*)b)+1);
if (y1 > y2) return  1;
if (y1 < y2) return -1;
return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////////

// sortArray function (here we want to implement the orderListArray[k][g]
// and run on that instead of predefined matrix which is included in the     code
int sortArray(int b[], size_t size)
{ // begin sortArray
int matrix[][2] = {{8,6}, {4,2}, {1,0}, {4,8}, {2,4},
    {4,3}, {1,2}, {2,2}, {8,3}, {5,5}};

printf("Original: ");
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(matrix); i++)
    printf("(%d,%d) ", matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]);
putchar('\n');

qsort(matrix, ARRAYSIZE(matrix), sizeof(*matrix), compare);

printf("Sorted  : ");
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(matrix); i++)
    printf("(%d,%d) ", matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]);
putchar('\n');

return 0;
} // end sortArray
```

Comment: // begin DescripANumbAPrice is wrong comment. just ignore it.

Comment: You know, you can edit your own question...And do you have an actual question here?

Comment: question has been edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `bona fide` 2D array.  That's an array of *arrays*, so the elements are arrays, and therefore your compare function receives pointers to arrays as its arguments.  Your comparison code is not actually wrong, but it would be a bit cleaner and clearer to acknowledge the correct types of the elements you are comparing:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int (*x1)[2] = a;
    const int (*x2)[2] = b;

    if ((*x1)[0] > (*x2)[0]) return  1;
    if ((*x1)[0] < (*x2)[0]) return -1;

    if ((*x1)[1] > (*x2)[1]) return  1;
    if ((*x1)[1] < (*x2)[1]) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

The main question seems to be represented by this code comment, however:

> here we want to implement the orderListArray[k][g] and run on that instead of predefined matrix

It's not an especial problem for `k` to be an adjustable parameter, but it complicates matters greatly for `g` to be adjustable.  To even declare your function requires either fudging types, or using a variable-length array.  Either way, your function signature does not provide enough information.  You must either know or assume *both* dimensions of your array, and you have only one parameter, `size`, to convey that information.

If you are assuming that the array to be sorted will be an array of pairs, as is `matrix` in your sample code, then simply write the function signature like so:

```
int sortArray(int b[][2], size_t size) // ...
```

and rely on the caller to provide the number of elements (pairs) via the `size` parameter.  Then you could call `qsort` like so:

```
qsort(b, size, sizeof(*b), compare);
```

It's a lot messier if the matrix rows are variable length, because then you have to either dynamically choose a comparison function that is specific to the correct length, or generalize your comparison function and convey the row length to it by some means other than its arguments (thus, probably via a file-scope variable).  Both of those approaches have significant drawbacks.

A third approach would be to rely on the caller of `sortArray()` to provide a suitable comparison function, but if you do that then you have to consider what value `sortArray()` is actually providing relative to calling `qsort()` directly.